# Any way to access a variable name from outside a function as a parameter of the function?

Tags: javascript, variables

I've got a simple JavaScript function which allows visitors to dynamically add input fields to a form.  In some cases I'll need to call this function several times on a page and I'm trying to simplify things by only creating one function and passing the necessary parameters to it.

My sticking point is that I need to have a counter for each category of input that I'm creating so that I can add/remove inputs as needed.  Here's what I've got so far:

```
var assigneeCounter = 1;
var uploadCounter = 1;


function addInput(fieldlabel, inputclasses, inputCounterID, inputCounter){
  alert(inputCounter);
}
```

The HTML to call this function is as follows:

```
<a href="javascript:addInput('Assignee','required-text', 'assignees', 'assigneeCounter');">Add Another Assignee</a>
<a href="javascript:addInput('File Uploads','', 'uploads', 'uploadCounter');">Add Another File Upload</a>
```

My goal is to have the function call look for the specific variable that relates to it (e.g. assigneeCounter for the Assignees inputs, uploadCounter for the Uploads, etc.).  However, when I alert that variable it simply writes "assigneeCounter" instead of "1".

I'm sure I'm just missing something fundamental about variable scope here and I'm no JavaScript expert so I figured I'd ask those who are.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it like this:

```
alert(window[inputCounter]);
```

Comment: Wow, I really don't no jack about JavaScript.  I've never used window before...worked like a champ!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If those variables are at global scope, you can access them through the `window` object:

```
window[inputCounter];
```

See [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name) for more details on how this works.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I really could stand to read more about JS.